# flag O_CREAT doesn't create file

Tags: c

I have a program that tries creating a file and writing in it, but for some reason when I use the O_CREAT flag I get an error

> No such file or directory

The part of the code that creates the error:

```
(char *) datafile = malloc(30);
strcpy(datafile, "~/Desktop/notes");
fd =  open(datafile, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); <----- here I get the error
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `open` with `O_CREAT` needs a third argument giving the file permissions. In this case probably 0666, and I think there's a constant for that value somewhere in `<unistd.h>`.

Answer (score 6):

```
"~/Desktop/notes"
```

There is no directory named `~` in there. Some programs (most notably shells like `bash`) expand `~` to the home directory of the current user, but `open` is not a shell and will not do that.

If you need a path relative to the home directory, you may do something like:

```
char* home = getenv("HOME");
if (home) {
     strcpy(datafile, home);
     strcat(datafile, "/Desktop/notes");
     ...
} else {
    ... report an error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `/home/{my_computer's_name}/Desktop` and it worked